# What is the consequence of performing deity worship using stale flowers?

Tags: scripture, rituals, worship, sin

In a deity worship, flower (or Pushpa) is an important Upachara. It is thus included among both Pancha Upacharas and the Shodasha Upacharas.

Now, I know that the act is very much proscribed in scriptures. I have read that in books.

But I have never found anything regarding the consequence of the act. In Hindu scriptures it is very common to find info like -- "you do this bad act and you'll have to suffer in this particular way either in this life or in the next."

So, here I'm looking for similar info from the scriptures.

- What is the consequence of performing deity worship using stale flowers?

BTW "stale flowers" here means "flowers that were plucked or bought on a day previous to the day when worship is performed". There are some flowers and leaves, however, that don't get "stale for ritual purposes" that soon. For example Bliva leaves and Tulasi leaves retain "freshness" for longer periods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest thing I found is in [Devi Bhagavata Purana, Eleventh Book, Chapter XXII](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/db/bk11ch22.htm). Though it is not the exact answer you asked but it is related.

> **If one performs the Homa with dry or stale substances, one is attacked with leprosy**; if anybody performs Homa with leavings of other food he becomes subdued by his enemy; if one does so with rude and harsh substances, he becomes poor and if one does with salty substances, he meets with a downward course, gets degraded in position and honour.

That chapter is only talking about the worship of Vishve Devas.

Comment: In South part of India, in temples people offer salty food in temples like Khichdi or Curd Rice or Veg Biryani. By above text that you mentioned, it looks like it should not be offered ?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto That text is only related to Vishve devas (I think).

Comment: Oh Ok! But I am not sure who are Vishve Devas. Also question is generic.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Yes, I know that this question is generic. But I have confirmed with Rickross in chat if I can give this answer. For Vishve devas, I have written [one answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20930/who-are-the-vishwedevas/21113#21113).