# Children of Viswa and Tamra

Tags: mahabharata

This [section](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01066.htm) of Mahabharata lists the 13 of Daksha's daughters married to Kashyapa. All the daughters but Viswa's children details are there. Anywhere else I can find (in Mahabharata) the details?

Also, in the next [section](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01067.htm), there is mention of Tamra. Is she one of Kashyapa's wife? Some links online does seems to suggest she is one of Daksha's daughter married to Kashyapa. But it is not clear from this section of the Bharata.

Comment: Tamra is one of Kashyapa’s wives who gives birth to the birds (Valmiki Ramayana [valmiki and Mahabharata are almost same], Srimad Bhagavatham, mention her as one of the 13 instead of Viswa). Viswa is most likely one of the 10 daughters of Daksha, who married Dharma Prajapati.

Comment: Refer: [Who are the Viswedevas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20930/who-are-the-vishwedevas) they are sons of Viswa and Dharma Rishi.