Who are the Viśvedevas that are mentioned in Shraddha ceremonies?
I have come across the term of Viśvedevas in various vedic texts pertaining to the performance of Shraddha ceremonies, however I am confused about who the texts refer to, as some definitions refer to them as a class of deiites, while others mention that the Viśvedevas refer to all devatas

Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20930/who-are-the-vishwedevas

This question is similar to: Who are the Vishwedevas?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
